# Declare variable in mysql syntax and query with dapper, get exception

Tags: c#, mysql, dapper

I hava sql sytanx like that :

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
            set @i = 0;
            select @i := @i+1 as Row,Target,StartDate,EndDate
            from (
                     select target,
                            StartDate,
                            EndDate
                     from t_xxx_table
                     where 1 = 1
                       and target= @TargetSn
                     order by StartDate desc
                 )
            COMMIT;
```

and C# code:

```
using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                var result = connection.Query<XXXClass>(sqlString, new
                {
                    TargetSn
                });
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception(e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Get the exception 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
I try to add 'Allow User Variables=True' in the connection string,but not work.
When I remove '@i',could be work.

The problem is dapper generation that can't handle '@i' and '@TargetSn', I guess..

Is there any solution to solve the problem ?

Comment: the targeSn has Initialization outside the block(using)

Comment: How, in your opinion, should the code understand where you have a parameter whose value should be substituted (`@TargetSn`), and where is a variable (`@i`) that should not be changed? I'm afraid this is a problem...

Comment: yup,,  I think the code can't understand where parameter should be change where's not.

Comment: I'd recommend to search for some another technique of parameter value insert - which is not used `@` char as a parameter marker and stays `@i` unchanged in the query text... in the most extreme case, use a direct replacement in the query text.

Comment: What are the full exception details, including the call stack? http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with the code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Row is a reserved word in mysql

use ticks for  text

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
set @i = 0;
select @i := @i+1 as 'Row',Target,StartDate,EndDate
from (
         select target,
                StartDate,
                EndDate
         from t_learning_note
         where 1 = 1
           and target= @TargetSn
         order by StartDate desc
     )
COMMIT;
```

As Akina pointed out, this runs in mysql, but could cause problems.

so you can use also backticks like

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
set @i = 0;
select @i := @i+1 as `Row`,Target,StartDate,EndDate
from (
         select target,
                StartDate,
                EndDate
         from t_learning_note
         where 1 = 1
           and target= @TargetSn
         order by StartDate desc
     )
COMMIT;
```

Comment: ROw is used in the as clause, there single quotes are ok. backticks you use when you use this Row as column name, but as string in c# it coud be a problem.

Comment: Yes, in this case, everything will be fine. However, in more complex cases, using the wrong quote symbol can lead to an error. Why get used to using the wrong quote symbol? And the uniformity is broken.

Comment: without quote chars is work in DataGrid(the mysql gui tool), add quote chars still get same error message..

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

SELECT (@i := @i+1) as `Row`,
       Target,
       StartDate,
       EndDate
FROM t_learning_note, 
     (SELECT @i:=0) init_variable
WHERE 1 = 1
  AND target= @TargetSn
ORDER BY StartDate DESC

COMMIT;
```

It is possible that the problem will not be fixed, but this code GUARANTEES that the calculated enumeration will be correct after successfull execution (whereas source query cannot).

Comment: Thanks... but I get the same error message 
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."..